# Does scala.collection.immutable.MapLike.mapValues breaks contract of scala.collection.immutable.Map?

Tags: scala

I wrote a code to transform values from `scala.collection.immutable.Map` to another values. I thought that it creates a new map, because **(!)** return type is `scala.collection.immutable.Map` but actually it returns a view and transform value from original map every time. From theoretical point of view transformation function may return different value for same key. So it is much better to copy `mapValues` returning result into new Map instead of transforming it every time.

Am right?

Comment: Well, it's a consideration of time vs memory. It might be better to create a new map, it might be better to create a view.

Comment: i dont think it breaking any contract. Definition of `mapValues` in `Map` is inheritted from `MapLike` and there is explicit _The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements._ in [api docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map).

Comment: Also _from theoretical points of view_ using side-effective functions within immutable collections leads to unpredicted effects